# logout button does not work despite of doing all I though was helpful

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

logout button does not work despite of doing all I though was helpful

```
Button logoutButton;

public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Create your fragment here
}

public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
    ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
    View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.account, container, false);

    logoutButton = (Button)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.LogoutButton);
    logoutButton.Click += LogoutButton_Click;

    return view;
}

private void LogoutButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StartActivity(typeof(LoginActivity));
}
```

Comment: Please format your answer properly, write your problem and not just paste code with a random title.

Comment: Please ask a specific question. *"Please help, my code does not work"* is not a question that's useful to others. What specifically is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue due to you lack of the `new Intent()` in the `StartActivity` like following code.

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
    ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
    View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.account, container, false);

    logoutButton = (Button)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.LogoutButton);
    logoutButton.Click += LogoutButton_Click;

    return view;
}

private void LogoutButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(LoginActivity)  ));
}
```

Here is runnning GIF.

[image]